# Time Conversion from str to float (00:54:50) -> (54.8) for example

Tags: time

I am trying to convert my time watched in a Netflix show to a float so I can total it up. I cannot figure out how to convert it. I have tried many ways, including:

```
temp['Minutes'] = temp['Duration'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

> Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00:54:45'
>
> ''' 2022-05-18 05:21:42 00:54:45 NaN Ozark: Season 4: Mud (Episode 13)
> NaN Amazon FTVET31DOVI2020 Smart TV 00:54:50 00:54:50 US (United
> States) Wednesday 2022-05-18
>
> '''

I have pulled the day of week and Day out but I would like to plot it just for fun and think the minutes would be the best to add up over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```py
var = '00:54:45'
var_array = var.split(':')

float = float(var_array[1]) + (float(var_array[2])/60)

print(float)
```

Output: 54.75 (from here u can round the second part, since it's a plus it wouldn't affect the first term)

Comment: If it is in a pandas data frame how would I do this? I think there are 50,000 entries.